# Bad performance on a simple SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

[image]I have a very simple SELECT statement that is taking much more time than it should. It only selects from one table with no JOINs, no computed columns. The table is not especially large (3 million rows, small row size). I have an appropriate index for the query (SQL Profile shows it's being used), which has been recently rebuilt (weekly) and the statistics are up to date (daily). I have tried putting the SELECT into a stored procedure, but that doesn't help. I also tried using WITH (NOLOCK), but there's not much improvement. It is frequently but not heavily queried -- it's not in the top 50 queries for our application. The result size is typically 1 - 5 rows. There is a fair amount of INSERT / UPDATE traffic on this table, too, a little less than the SELECT traffic.

The stored procedure with the SELECT is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fetchcurrentichecklistitemanswers] @p_ichecklistitemid Int
AS

DECLARE @ichecklistitemid Int = @p_ichecklistitemid

SELECT * FROM ichecklistitemanswers WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ichecklistitemid = @ichecklistitemid AND status = 2 ORDER BY ordering ASC

GO
```

Any thoughts on what else could be slowing down a simple SELECT like this?

[edit -- added execution plan] The query runs fast in Management Studio (instant) but in the application, the query time averages more than 1 second.

Comment: Did you tried your query with execution plan ?

Comment: We need to see the execution plan. perhaps there isn't an index on ichecklistitemid or status? The order by will slow it down too. Could be a huge table... etc

Comment: Parameter sniffing may be an issue, you can try to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: NOLOCK is not a magic go fast button. It comes with some very serious baggage that most people don't fully understand. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

You could add index on that column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON ichecklistitemanswers(ichecklistitemid)
INCLUDE(status, ordering) WHERE status=2;
```